# when loading on Android, circle is too close up, i think I need a bitmap code but dont no where.. any idea?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

`public class Sample extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new Draw (this));

```
} 

private class Draw extends View {
    public Draw (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint1.setAntiAlias(true);


        Paint paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);


        Paint paint3 = new Paint();
        paint3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        paint3.setAntiAlias(true);


        Paint paint4 = new Paint();
        paint4.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint4.setAntiAlias(true);

        Paint paint5 = new Paint();
        paint5.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint5.setAntiAlias(true);


        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 180, paint1);


        canvas.drawLine(220, 180, 280, 40, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(220, 180, 280, 40, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(260, 170, 370, 100, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(260, 170, 370, 100, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(380, 200, 260, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(380, 200, 260, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(350, 300, 260, 240, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(350, 300, 260, 240, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(280, 370, 230, 260, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(280, 370, 230, 260, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(200, 380, 200, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(200, 380, 200, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(100, 350, 200, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(100, 350, 200, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(40, 300, 200, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(40, 300, 200, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(120, 200, 20, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(120, 200, 20, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(40, 100, 200, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(40, 100, 200, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(120, 40, 200, 200, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(120, 40, 200, 200, paint2);

        canvas.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 20, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 20, paint2); 


    }
}
```

}`

I want to show the circle but when loading this on android sdk it comes out too big, I believe I need a bitmap code, but dont know where to place it...can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hundred percent sure what you are trying to achieve, yet if the circle appears to big, you can change the `radius` of it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there...I have found a solution for this problem thanks...but now I have problems creating a button over canvas in extend view as stated in another post